# How to get value from JSON format

Tags: python, json, request

I am using Python request module to get API response. The response is should be JSON format. From the response how do I retrieve the specific value?

Example of API response:

```
{
id: 2337975,
sha: "eac6910f89883110e673db27456b67f542df6d75",
ref: "mail-gun",
status: "manual",
created_at: "2021-03-01T09:15:02.409Z",
updated_at: "2021-03-01T09:19:14.983Z",
web_url: "https://gitlab.com/optimus/optimus-ci/-/pipelines/2337975"
}
```

From here I want retrieve on ID :2337975 assign into a variable in Python.

Here is my code

```
url = f'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{pid}/pipelines?updated_after={update_after}&ref={branch}&status=manual'    
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer xxxxxxxx'} 
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

output = json.loads(response.text)
print(output)
```

I can print the whole JSON format by print(output), but I only want to get a Id value.

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
output = json.loads(response.text)
```

to this: (using `json` function you can receive the json response in string format)
load the response into a `python dictionary`

```
response_json = json.loads(response.json())
```

and access the `id` key from response dictionary

```
variable = response_json["id"]
```

Comment: I tried this but i got "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list" error

Answer (score 0):

You should save this JSON code in a .json file, then you can open it, load it and then use variable ["id"].

Answer (score 0):

parse the json and use the id as key in json to extract.

```
loaded_json = json.loads(json_data)
    for x in loaded_json:
        print("%s: %d" % (x, loaded_json[id]))
```

Answer (score 0):

since the returned value of a json is an object (JavaScript Object Notation) you can treat it as such and just destructure the object with the [] notation as other pointed out response_json["id"]

Answer (score 0):

I solve this using a naive way. which is convert the object to JSON > python list > python dictionary

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxyDict)
response_list = response.json()
response_dict = response_list[0]
print(response_dict["id"])
```